# Relation between Floyd and Gromov boundaries of hyperbolic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory

Let $G$ be a hyperbolic group. Consider the Floyd boundary as defined in https://www.unige.ch/math/folks/karlsson/free.pdf by Karlsson. For a Floyd function $f$, we denote the Floyd boundary of $G$ by $\partial_f(G)$. Let $\partial G$ be the Gromov boundary of $G$. It is known that there exists a Floyd function $f$ such that $\partial_f(G)$ is homeomorphic to $\partial G$ (for example, see Corollary 7.2.M in Gromov's "Hyperbolic groups, Essays in Group Theory"). Recently, I came across with the paper https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/40302787.pdf where the authors have discussed relationship between Gromov and Floyd boundaries in Corollary 2.3. But their definition of Floyd function is different from the one mentioned in Karlsson's paper. So, my question is the following:

Is $\partial_f(G)$ homeomorphic to $\partial G$ for any Floyd function $f$ as in Karlsson's paper?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any Floyd function $f$ (as in Karlsson's paper) not decaying exponentially too fast, the Gromov and Floyd compactifications indeed coincide. In fact, there is a more general result for relatively hyperbolic groups, namely for such Floyd functions, the Floyd compactification covers the Bowditch boundary and the pre-image of conical limit points are reduced to a single point.

More precisely, let $\Gamma$ be a relatively hyperbolic group. It is proved in Corollary 2.8 of Gerasimov and Potyagailo's paper Quasi-isometric maps and Floyd boundaries of relatively hyperbolic groups that there exists a parameter $\lambda_0$ such that for any Floyd function $f$ satisfying that $f(n)\geq \lambda_0^n$, we have

1. there exists a continuous, surjective and equivariant map $\Phi_f$ from the Floyd compactification to the Bowditch compactification that extends the identity
2. the pre-image by $\Phi_f$ of a conical limit point is a singleton.

Since a hyperbolic group is relatively hyperbolic and every point in the Gromov boundary is conical (in the sense of convergence actions), you get the desired result.

Note that the Floyd boundary was introduced by Floyd in 1980 in the paper Group completions and limit sets of Kleinian groups, in order to study the boundary of Kleinian groups, so this result is intentional.

Actually we have more for hyperbolic groups. Let $\Gamma$ be a hyperbolic group. The Gromov boundary can be endowed by the so-called visual distance (of parameter say $a$). This visual distance $d_a$ is approximately given by $d_a(\xi,\zeta)=e^{-ad(\xi,\zeta)}$ as soon as $a\geq a_0$. Now take an exponential Floyd function $f:n\mapsto f(n)=\lambda^n$. Then, for $a\geq a_0$ and $\lambda=e^{-a}$, not only are the Floyd and Gromov compactifications equal but the visual distance and the induced Floyd distance on the boundary are bi-Lipschitz.

This was considered as Folklore for a long time and was recently written down by Potyagailo and Yang, see Proposition 6.1 in their paper Hausdorff dimension of boundaries of relatively hyperbolic groups.
The reason I'm mentionning this is because the proof in their paper is very intuitive and you can see from it why the Floyd and Gromov boundary must coincide.